# How to alert id when different row is clicked?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I have two results in my select db which are text_1 and text_2 they have different ids, but when I click text_2 it alerts the id of text_1

my php echo

```
echo'<p><input id="textid" type="hidden" value="'.$msg->id.'">'.$msg->text.'</p>';
```

this is my js code

```
var getid= document.getElementById('textid').value; 
    $("p").click(function(){    
        alert(getid);   
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an `id` that is the same for both inputs. `ID`s should be *unique*, only 1 id per page. But I'm guessing since you didn't post more than 1 line of HTML.

I changed your `id` to `class` on the input tag.

Then move the variable *inside* the click function to target the clicked `p`. And the proper way to get an input value is to use `.val()` not `.value`.

```js
$("p").click(function(){    
      var getid= $(this).children('.textid').val(); 
        alert(getid);   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><input class="textid" type="hidden" value="VALUE IS 1">'.$msg->text.'</p>

<p><input class="textid" type="hidden" value="VALUE IS 2">'.$msg->text.'</p>
```

Comment: another question please, since there are 2 results I would like to click text_1 id and show its data while the text_2 is hidden, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
echo'<p><input id="textid_1" type="hidden" value="'.$msg->id.'">'.$msg->text.'</p>';
echo'<p><input id="textid_2" type="hidden" value="'.$msg->id.'">'.$msg->text.'</p>';
```

**JS**

```
$("p").click(function(){
    alert($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Comment: BTW `id="textid_1"` make no sense. Change it to a general class. And you can also vote up answer if it is OK. Thanks :)

Comment: I mean i need both. So sad :D